# Difference between `width: fit-content` and `width: 100%`

Tags: css

What is the difference between

```css
div {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

and

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

width 100% will stretch to the whole width of the parent

fit-content will make it as wide as it's children

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/

Comment: actually, divs are 100% width by default - you don't need to specify it. Use display: inline-block instead of width: fit-content - it is a more common, standard way to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

The best to understand is to try it ...

```css
<style>
    .parent {
        background-color: red;
        width: 500px;
    }
    .child-fit {
        background-color: blue;
        width: fit-content;
    }
    .child-100 {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-fit">
        <p>FIT CONTENT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child-100">
        <p>100%</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).